# Rewrite query string with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite this url

```
category.php?cat=computers
```

to

```
category/computers
```

Or, is it the other way round?

How do I do that with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

The rule is:

```
    RewriteRule    ^category/(.+)/?$    category.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]
```

your .htaccess should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #if the name of the php file is the same of the path, you have to remove MultiViews
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews          
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^category/(.+)/?$    category.php?cat=$1    [NC,L]    
</IfModule>
```